# html/css make multiple sections that drop shadow one on another

Tags: html, css

I have multiple sections placed one after another, each of them should drop shadow on the next one. Number of sections might change

My current idea is to create about 10 css rules like

```
section {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
section:nth-child(1){
    z-index:10
}
section:nth-child(2) {
    z-index:9
}
...
```

This approach has obvious flaw, so my question is - is there more elegant way to achieve this using only html/css? 
Set z-index automatically somehow or make shadows in completely different way?

Comment: Apply the shadow via a pseudo element within each section instead perhaps? Absolutely positioned at the top, should give the same effect, but without the need of having to deal with several layers on the z axis ...

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible without using JavaScript or a pseudo-element.

Just using the `transform-style: preserve-3d` property and a specific rotation.

```css
.section {
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transform: rotateX(1deg);
}


.wrapper {
  transform: rotateX(-1deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it via html/css. But you can use javascript:

```
for (var i=$("section").length; i > 1; i++){
    $("section:nth-child(" + i +")").css ({"z-index":i});
}
```

And css:

```
section {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

Comment: No it's not impossible using CSS and HTML only.